# Recording UI test in Xcode, but the record button doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to record a UI test but the record button doesn't do anything. It is not disabled--as I can see people have asked about before--it just doesn't do anything when I click it. At least nothing I can observe. It stays the red round button and doesn't show a stop-button after I press it either.

I have absolutely no idea where to look for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Recording UI tests requires:

- A UI test target for your project
- Accessibility information for your UI elements
- OS X v10.11 or greater
- iOS 9 or greater

Once your app is ready to record a test, open a source file in the UI test target and insert the cursor in a test method. the `testExample()` will already be available so put your cursor in that function. The record button will get enabled. Make sure that the currently selected target has the application installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I wrote, the button *is* enabled. Clicking on it simply doesn't do anything. It stays enabled and, as far as I can see, nothing happens. I can click on it as many times as I like but it never switches to a stop button and the application doesn't start (and nothing happens if I start it myself before I click record either). Because it is enabled I think it should be working but it doesn't. I think I have all of the four points you mention set up correctly

Comment: Are you using a simulator or a real device?

Comment: It was in the simulator. I connected an iPad and now the button is disabled (on both the simulator and iPad). How connecting the device changed the behaviour in XCode I have no idea. The problem might be that it should be disabled but just didn't show that?

Comment: In iPad can you please follow above steps and check the output?

Comment: When I went back to the simulator again and did a test the button was enabled again and this time I could record a test... I have no clue as to why but if it works now I am happy... it works both on ipad and simulator now.

Comment: I guess it solves itself if you switch back and forth between the target a few times.

Comment: Great enjoy your UI test cases.